# Submitting login form in WKWebView inside an iOS share extension causes the share extension to close

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, wkwebview

### Background:

We are building a React Native app which allows users to create posts that include a quote from a blog post or news article. To achieve this, we have built a share extension, which displays a React Native view inside a modal. Inside the RN view we are using [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) (which renders as a WKWebView on iOS), to display the page that was shared, allowing the user to select some text on the page (which is fed back to our app via an injected content script), and continue to create a post.

### The problem:

Some news sites that our users want to share from have paywalls, e.g. FT, NY Times etc. - on these sites the user has to log in inside the webview. It's not ideal, but once they have logged in, as we have cookies enabled on the webview, their session will be remembered. This solution works well on Android, and works well on iOS when sharing from Safari.

When sharing from an app on iOS however, once the user submits the login form inside the webview, the share extension closes, taking the user back to the app that initiated the share action.

Here is a video demonstration of the issue occurring in the Guardian app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFnh1x3j4xs

### Observations:

When observing requests that occur within the webview using the `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` prop of the `WebView` component, upon submitting the login form, there are two requests where iOS reports the `navigationType` as `formSubmitted`.

By checking the `navigationType` inside of the `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` method, I was able to allow the first `formSubmitted` request to go through, but cancel the subsequent one. This prevented the share extension from closing, but upon clicking a link to go back to the home page, the share extension was closed.

My current theory is that the app which initiates the share, is somehow hooking into the form submit event, as these apps generally use webviews for their own login process - so although this webview is running in our own process, perhaps the app still somehow hooks into the process.

It is worth noting that this behaviour is inconsistent between news apps, presumably due to differences in the way they handle their login process.

Initially this issue was occurring in the BBC app as well, but at some point stopped occurring without us making any changes, so it is somewhat intermittent, or perhaps based on stored data/cookies.

### Summary

We would like to fully understand why this behaviour occurs, and we're hoping there is a solution or workaround that will prevent the share extension from closing when the login form is submitted.